# how to get Azure Data Factory currently running pipelines?

Tags: azure-data-factory

is there a way to list out all running pipelines (with Run Id)
or completed pipelines

.Net SDK way preferred

Answer (score 0):

> You will get List of all Azure Data Factory running pipelines using below **RunQueryOrderBy**.

[image: ref1]

**Reference:**

[RunQueryOrderBy Constructor (Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datafactory.models.runqueryorderby.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_DataFactory_Models_RunQueryOrderBy__ctor)